# installations of cake php website in linux server

Tags: linux, cakephp

I've developed a website in cakephp and it is running successfully in localhost of my windows operating system.Now i need to make it run on Linus static IP server.I also need to know that what are all the softwares needed to install and implementation procedures to upload it and where to upload it.Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Upload all sub directories under your root app in `/www/html` folder through ftp or file manager. Change the `app/Config/database.php` database connection path. Assign 777 permission to `tmp` folder under app folder.

Comment: You must sure, some packages must be installed on your server including PEAR package, PDO driver etc. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#requirements

Answer (score 1):

You have to research a bit more on the net, there's plenty of answers guiding you how to do it. Stackoverflow is more pertaining to specific coding questions. I personally prefer using amazon ec2 for uploading my cakephp applications.

There's lots of tutorials on how to set up a free tier linux server instance on ec2 all over the net. Here's a great one:

http://www.comtechies.com/2013/01/how-to-host-dynamic-php-website-on.html

Once you have your instance set up, this is what you have to do:

In apache your public folder will be /var/www/ so anything you put in there will be directly accessible to people by URL. Use putty to connect to your server.

```
    sudo service apache2 stop
```

This will stop your apache server for security reasons while you upload etc.

Copy your project to  `/var/www/cakephp` such that your webroot lies in `/var/www/cakephp/app/webroot`.

type the following to describe location of cakePHP

```
nano /var/www/cakePHP/app/webroot/index.php
```

Go to the line starting with `define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH'` and make it `define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS . 'var' . DS . 'www' . DS . cakephp . DS . lib')` - assuming `cakephp/lib` is to be found in `/var/www/cakephp/lib`

Next, set the new document root:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

and wherever you see `/var/www` change it to `/var/www/cakephp/app/webroot.`
Also, in the change `allowoverride none` to `allowoverride all` the first two times they occur from the top of the document.

To allow apache to access your files and write to cache, execute the following commands:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/myproject -R
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/myproject/tmp -R
```

To allow CSS to be applied properly:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Now everything should be working according to plan. If you have any further questions do hit me back!

Comment: Thanks for reply.A new error occurred now." cakephp couldnot load class debugkitloglistenerlog ".can u tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: This is the complete error report when i open it it on my browser.

Comment: Could not load class DebugKitLogListenerLog

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Stack Trace

CORE/Cake/Log/LogEngineCollection.php line 42 → LogEngineCollection::_getLogger(string)
'DebugKitLogListener'
CORE/Cake/Log/CakeLog.php line 200 → LogEngineCollection->load(string, array)